# MVC controller method not being triggered by jquery in the view

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following method in a controller called "ProductController":

```
public ActionResult LoadProducts(int prodID)
{
    return View();
}
```

I'm trying to trigger it from a view cshtml page this way:

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/jscript">
    $('#MyProducts').change(function () {
        var selectedID = $(this).val();
        $.get('/Product/LoadProducts/' + selectedID, function (data) {
            window.alert(selectedID);
        });
    });
</script>
}

<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new
    { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
       @Html.DropDownList("MyProducts", 
       (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.MyProducts as 
           IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select")
    }
</div>
```

The call to the jquery works when I change the value in the drop down, as I tested it via the popup box, but getting it to trigger the action method in the controller is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Try renaming`prodID` to just `id` so that the default routing matches.

Comment: Awesome, that worked, thank you stephen, I will mark it solved.

Comment: @stephen.vakil: this isn't the right way, the right way is to set the route using `[HttpGet]` attribute.

Comment: @Transcendent I tried using the [HttpGet] attribute and it did not work.

Comment: @user2471103: You used the wrong route template. Check my answer.

Comment: What the "right" way and wrong are are is subjective.  I would not want to put in a custom route for every action like that when just using the right naming convention suffices.

Comment: @stephen.vakil: The point is to show to the OP what is causing the problem. Although what you mentioned surely works, it does not describe why the problem has been caused and how it can be fixed in a standard way. Changing the property name to `id` is more of a workaround or a trick.

Comment: @Transcendent I strongly disagree.  It's not a workaround or trick.  It's how the default routes are intended to work.  MVC is a convention-based framework and the default convention is that the parameter is named `id`.  If you name your parameter something else, you must alter the route table in some manner.  If there are 30 action methods each with a different parameter name then you need 30 attributes bloating your routing table.

Comment: @stephen.vakil: Try to imagine a case where you both have an `id` and a `productId`. Then your solution will not work.

Comment: @stephen.vakil: Multiple required parameters is something which is very common particularly in Web API.

Comment: @Transcendent sounds like premature optimization to me to imagine scenarios where the default route doesn't work and therefore to never use the default route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, you can use `HttpGetArribute` to define the route. Without specifying the route, the parameter is considered as optional and it should be called as `Product/LoadProducts?prodId=1`. Example of `HttpGetAttribute`:

```
[HttpGet("[controller]\[action]\{prodId}")]
public ActionResult LoadProducts(int prodID)
{
     return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set Url by `Url.Action`

```
 var Url='@(Url.Action("ActionName","ConttrolerName"))';
```

and Put the variable name of the sent with the same variable received

`SelectedID` to `ProdID`

---

```
<script type="text/jscript">
        $('#MyProducts').on("change",function () {
            var Url='@(Url.Action("LoadProducts","Product"))';
            var SelectedProdID = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
            $.get( Url,{prodID:SelectedProdID}, function (data) {
                window.alert(selectedID);
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:  use script type="text/javascript".  I am not an expert on which browsers support "jscript" but after 20 years of development I can assure you all browsers support javascript.

Also, I would discourage you from using the code which Farhad Bagherlo posted.  If at all possible you should avoid using razor code inside your script tag because you may want to move this code into separate JS files or later on refactor to use TypeScript.  Also, why invoke a method on the server to get an endpoint/url if you already know the path which is needed.  seems wasteful.  However, you could use the method he outlined to ensure that you are actually giving the correct URL.  If his code works then what is the value of "Url"?  (also, the client side standard for naming variables is camelCase, so url should be lower.)

If you are debugging your code and set a breakpoint in your controller. then you should be able to get it to break on that line by simply navigating to that route.

If you go to http://localhost:post/Product/LoadProducts/1 does it actually break on that line in Visual Studio?

Edit:  @Transcendent is correct and would get my vote, need to understand how routing is defined vs arguments/parameters passed to the action method.  Nice call Transcendent!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Collin on that using razor in your javascript marries them and that can be a pain if you try to split the js into its own file.  I recently had to go through it.

Edit: This is just to show how to use `Url.Action` and still be able to separate js into a separate file by the use of `data` property in the div

What I suggest is doing something like:

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#MyProducts').change(function () {
        var url = $('#mydiv').data('url') + '?prodId=' + selectedID;

        var selectedID = $(this).val();
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            window.alert(selectedID);
        });
    });
</script>
}

<div id="mydiv" data-url="@(Url.Action("ActionName","ConttrolerName"))">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new
    { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
       @Html.DropDownList("MyProducts", 
       (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.MyProducts as 
           IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select")
    }
</div>
```

Comment: But the use of section tag does not solve the problem of `separating java script from cshtml views`. It only allows for better organization of code.

Comment: @Transcendent yes, that's true, I just wanted to show that if his code was like the edited version that I posted he then could separate it.  I was not showing the separation itself here.  Just the use of `data` on the div and then being able to retrieve the value in js.